# GSON: knowing what type of object to convert to?

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm looking into using Google's [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for my Android project that will request JSON from my web server.  The JSON returned will be either...

1) A successful response of a known type (e.g.: class "User"):

```
{
    "id":1,
    "username":"bob",
    "created_at":"2011-01-31 22:46:01",
    "PhoneNumbers":[
        {
            "type":"home",
            "number":"+1-234-567-8910"
        },
        {
            "type":"mobile",
            "number":"+1-098-765-4321"
        }
    ]
}
```

2.) An unsuccessful response, which will always take on the same basic structure below.

```
{
    "error":{
        "type":"Error",
        "code":404,
        "message":"Not Found"
    }
}
```

I'd like GSON to convert to the correct type depending on the existence of the `error` key/value pair above.  The most practical way I can think to do this is as follows, but I'm curious if there's a better way.

```
final String response = client.get("http://www.example.com/user.json?id=1");
final Gson gson = new Gson();

try {
    final UserEntity user = gson.fromJson(response, UserEntity.class);
    // do something with user
} catch (final JsonSyntaxException e) {
    try {
        final ErrorEntity error = gson.fromJson(response, ErrorEntity.class);
        // do something with error
    } catch (final JsonSyntaxException e) {
        // handle situation where response cannot be parsed
    }
}
```

This is really just pseudocode though, because in the first catch condition, I'm not sure how to test whether the key `error` exists in the JSON response.  So I guess my question is twofold:

1. Can I / how can I use GSON to test the existence of a key, and make a decision on how to parse based upon that?
2. Is this what others in a similar situation are doing with GSON, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you'd normally want to do is to have your server return an actual error code along with the JSON error response. Then you read the response as an `ErrorEntity` if you get an error code and as a `UserEntity` if you get 200. Obviously this requires a little more dealing with the details of communication with the server than just turning a URL in to a String, but that's how it is.

That said, I believe another option would be to use a custom `JsonDeserializer` and a class that can return either a value or an error.

```
public class ValueOrErrorDeserializer<V> implements JsonDeserializer<ValueOrError<V>> {
  public ValueOrError<V> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
                                     JsonDeserializationContext context) {
    JsonObject object = json.getAsJsonObject();
    JsonElement error = object.get("error");
    if (error != null) {
      ErrorEntity entity = context.deserialize(error, ErrorEntity.class);
      return ValueOrError.<V>error(entity);
    } else {
      Type valueType = ((ParameterizedType) typeOfT).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
      V value = (V) context.deserialize(json, valueType);
      return ValueOrError.value(value);
    }
  }
}
```

You'd then be able to do something like this:

```
String response = ...
ValueOrError<UserEntity> valueOrError = gson.fromJson(response,
    new TypeToken<ValueOrError<UserEntity>>(){}.getType());
if (valueOrError.isError()) {
  ErrorEntity error = valueOrError.getError();
  ...
} else {
  UserEntity user = valueOrError.getValue();
  ...
}
```

I haven't tried that code out, and I'd still recommend using the HTTP error code, but it gives you an example of how you can use a `JsonDeserializer` to decide what to do with some JSON.

Comment: The error code change should be simple in how I have my web app configured.  I'll have to toy around and figure out whether removing the "error" key in the resulting JSON or using something like the above will work out better for me.  Huge thanks for your detailed answer, I really appreciate it!

Comment: To follow up, I made sure my web server is not returning an HTTP status 200 whenever an error response is expected, and I changed the JSON error response to not include the encapsulating "error" key, only including the "type", "code", and "message" instead.  Everything is now working as I'd like for it to.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Almost, but it JsonDeserializer is an interface, so you need to implement it, not extend it.

Comment: What is ValueOrError class ?

Comment: @alvinm93: It's just a simple value object that may either contain a `T` or an `ErrorEntity`. Didn't seem worth writing out.